# Single mechanism for reversible encryption in PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The problem arose to encrypt data transmitted between client and server using a key without using https (the key is transmitted separately, that's another story.)
So. Are interested in the mechanism. I know that there is no built-in JS encryption functions, and PHP are many, but not all normal decode UTF8.

Question: Is there a ready-made solutions (if possible with examples) of such a problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "but not all normal decode UTF8". Encryption algorithms care nothing about the character encoding of plaintext.

Comment: How secure do you want the encryption to be? Also, UTF8 is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a well-solved problem. The solution is SSL. There is no other solution, and no other solution can exist *without* SSL to securely deliver the code to the browser. You cannot implement this in JavaScript with https. It is impossible. And if you have HTTPs, you don't need to implement additional security on top of that.

Comment: Encryption algorithms don't encrypt characters, they encrypt bytes. So it doesn't matter if it's in UTF-8 or ASCII or any other encoding. If the encryption and decryption process is messing up your data, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I do not ask you how to deliver code.
Imagine that it is administered at least manually.
I am interested in encryption and decryption.

Comment: I've linked you to several solutions in my answer, but the fact remains: If any part of your app is being delivered insecurely (that is, over the Internet, without HTTPS), your *entire app* is fundamentally insecure and no amount of encryption in JS will save you.

Comment: OP, what @meagar means is that without HTTPS you cannot trust anything sent to the client. The entire JS code (not the key, but the code that does the decryption itself) can be intercepted by an attacker and replaced with something of their choosing. So the client thinks it's decrypting things, but it's actually doing whatever the attacker wants.

Comment: For example: imagine the original JS function decrypt looks like this `function decrypt(key, msg) { return AES.decrypt(key, msg); // does AES decryption }`. Without SSL, an attacker can simply replace the whole thing with `function decrypt(key, msg) { return 'Attack at midnight'; }` and the user will think it's decrypting the message, but actually it's just returning whatever the attacker wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall I found the solution to my problem. I used the algorithm AES CBC 256 bit. Library Gibberish AES (https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes) and fork on php (https://github.com/ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php/blob/master/GibberishAES.php)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem with [pidCrypt](https://www.pidder.com/pidcrypt/) which has a working RSA implementation in JavaScript. There is also [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) which I've never used.

I recently had to implement this in virtually the only case where it's valid to do so: We were storing data offline in the application cache, and a non-negotiable business requirement stated that it be encrypted while there. Unless you're doing something similar, the answer is to use SSL and throw out any hope of implementing a JS solution to this problem. You *need* SSL to securely transmit the code to the browser, or any encryption you do there is fundamentally insecure.

Comment: Except that without SSL you're vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks and suddenly the attacker can inject arbitrary code into your browser and steal the keys. SSL isn't *just* about encryption, it's about trusting the source of data and the integrity of that data.

Comment: I know, this is why I said you need SSL to securely deliver the *code*, as in, the rest of the bits of the web app. Assuming he's accessing it over the Internet, it doesn't matter how securely his keys are delivered, the *entire client-side environment* is insecure.

Comment: Ah, I see where you're getting at.